# Div Following Mouse Triggers Mouseout and Mousemove Event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, mouseout

I'm trying to make a div follow the mouse, but only while the mouse is inside of another div. I've made some progress, but when the div that follows the mouse is revealed, the `mouseout` event is triggered causing it to disappear again. Then, the `mousemove` event causes it to show up and it repeated in an infinite loop. How can this loop be avoided?

HTML

```
<div class="navbar" rel="#box1">Link</div>
<div class="box" id="box1" align="center"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar").mousemove(function(e){         
        $($(this).attr('rel')).show();       
        $(".box").css({             
            top: -80 + "px",             
            left: (e.pageX - 300) + "px"        
        });    
    });     
    $(".navbar").mouseout(function(e){         
        $($(this).attr('rel')).hide();   
    });
});​
```

CSS

```
.navbar{
width: 90%;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid #f00;
margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
display: block;
}
.box{
    width: 616px;
    height: 474px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/4fV4o.png);
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: try adding the attribute `pointer-events: none` to the div that follows. Note that this is not supported by all browsers. More info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know about the pointer-events CSS property. If anyone is looking for an IE alternative [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)